# Verilog floating point arithmetic at compile time?

Tags: verilog, modelsim

My Verilog testbench code defines a module with these parameters:

```
parameter PHASE_BITS = 32;
parameter real MAX_PHASE = 1 << PHASE_BITS;
```

I cannot get `MAX_PHASE` to have the expected value `4294967296` or its approximation; ModelSim shows me `0` instead. This despite the fact that `MAX_PHASE` is declared real.

I guess there's some integer overflow involved, because it works fine if `PHASE_BITS` is lowered to 31.

How do I make this parameter be equal to 2 to the power of another parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the right-hand expression itself:

```
1 << PHASE_BITS
```

It is evaluated before considering the type of the variable it is stored into. Because `1` is an integer literal and integers in Verilog are signed 32 bits, the `<<` operator (left shift operator) will output an integer of the same type, and will cause an overflow if `PHASE_BITS` is higher than 31.

We could force `1` to be a real literal instead:

```
1.0 << PHASE_BITS
```

But this causes a compile time error, as `<<` is not defined for real values.

Let's use plain 2-power-to-N:

```
2.0 ** PHASE_BITS
```

This will yield the desired result, `4.29497e+09`.